# How to increase the request timeout?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How do I increase the TimeOut for Get or GetTaskAsync? (Using Facebook C# SDK 6)

Seems like they have a timeout of 15 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use FacebookClient.HttpWebRequestFactory. Since it is hidden from intellisense you might not see it in VS depending on your settings.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Http web request factory.
    /// </summary>
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public virtual Func<Uri, HttpWebRequestWrapper> HttpWebRequestFactory
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

You might want to do something like this.

```
FacebookClient.HttpWebRequestFactory = url => {
  var request = new HttpWebRequestWrapper((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url));
  request.Timeout = .....;
  return request;
};
```

This requires v6 at minimum.

for v5, you need to override a protected method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the http web request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The url of the http web request.</param>
    /// <returns>The http helper.</returns>
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    protected virtual HttpWebRequestWrapper CreateHttpWebRequest(Uri url);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `GetTaskAsync` version, you need to pass a cancellation token. The `Timeout` value set on the request is not honored.

```
var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
await client.GetTaskAsync<T>(path, parameters, cancellationSource.Token);
```