# C# - Facebook SDK time out when get friend more than 1000

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I used Facebook SDK to connect with Graph API (get here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/) and when received `access _token` I make a test with the account has 689 friends and it worked as well, but when I switch to another account has more than 3000 friends, it was got an exception and not return anything.

I has been researching for it and someone recommended me to use `GetTaskSync()` method in `FacebookClient` class, but I don't understand how to use this function (searched but got nothing).

Please help me, thanks in advance !

Comment: `it was got an exception and not return anything` can you post this error as you didn't explain what the exact error was.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924610/how-to-increase-the-request-timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Stackoverflow question describes using bundles to tell Facebook what upper limit to use for number of friends.

Use the Bundle object, call putInt("limit", 5000), then execute a GraphRequest using executeAsync.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33409920/154186

Comment: Problem solved with the link above, thanks Russell and everyone !